# Javascript XML Parsing Error, Unclosed CDATA Section

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, cdata

I am using the following lines of javascript to parse an XML string into an XML DOM object:

```
this._xmlParser = new DOMParser();
this._xmlDoc = this._xmlParser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
```

My xml string looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<event>
  <id>41717876</id>
  <start>2011-08-16T10:16</start>
  <end>2011-08-16T10:16</end>
  <title>New Calendar Event</title>
  <location>
    <line>Your location goes here.</line>
  </location>
  <description>
    <line>Your description goes here.</line>
  </description>
  <!-- %%spider:url%% -->
  <further-info><![CDATA[ hello&goodbye ]]></further-info>
  <tag>all</tag>
  <url>www.google.com</url>
</event>
```

The CDATA section seems to be well-formed.  Why am I receiving a parser error for an unclosed CDATA section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I discovered that the source of my problem had to do with the browser response limiting the size of text nodes in xml-rpc calls.  I found the following useful note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411229/size-limit-to-javascript-node-nodevalue-field):

> "Also important to note is that although the specifications say that
>   no matter how much text exists between tags, it should all be in one
>   text node, in practice this is not always the case. In Opera 7-9.2x
>   and Mozilla/Netscape 6+, if the text is larger than a specific maximum
>   size, it is split into multiple text nodes. These text nodes will be
>   next to each other in the childNodes collection of the parent
>   element."

The response I was receiving to the browser had unknowingly split my text node into multiple text nodes.  Heads up for anyone who has a similar issue.